# Rails account_params missing parameters from backbone `.save()`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, typescript, backbone-model, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am trying to create a user account using Backbone 1.1.2 and Rails 4.2.beta1.

In backbone I am calling:

```
public create(){
    var email:string = $('#create-account-email').val(), password:string = $('#create-account-password').val(), passconf:string = $('#create-account-password-confirm').val();
    this.model.set({email: email, password: password, password_confirmation: passconf});
    this.model.save(null, {success: this.success, error: this.error});
}
```

which correctly calls the rails `create` method in my webservice with the following request parameters:

```
{"email":"test@test.com","password":"123456","password_confirmation":"123456"}
```

It is going through the filter method

```
def account_params
  #breakpoint
  params.require(:account).permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :email)
end
```

but if I place a breakpoint in the above noted spot and inspect the `params` object I get:

```
{"email"=>"test@test.com", 
 "password"=>"123456", 
 "password_confirmation"=>"123456", 
 "controller"=>"accounts", 
 "action"=>"create", 
 "account"=>{"email"=>"test@test.com"}, 
 "format"=>"json"}
```

Which to me looks correct at first glance. But the account creation fails because the password is `nil`

if inspecting the result of `account_params` I only get:

```
{"email" => "test@test.com")
```

Why is the password not being included in the account parameter object. I am using all default sacaffolded code with rails and default configuration for Backbone.

Comment: can you post your form?

Comment: @Mandeep I edited the above code for you. It is a form, but I'm reading it off the form using `$().val()` so I included that code for you.

Comment: Ah alright and how are you sending these params to server? Looking at your params hash they don't seem to nest properly

Comment: @Mandeep I'm currently just letting backbone do it's thing. Do I need to modify the way backbone sends the parameters. It was my understanding that backbone + rails *just work*

Comment: No, they don't *just work* together out of the box. Backbone wants to send `{p1:v1, p2:v2}` but Rails wants to see `{model_name: {p1:v1, p2:v2}}`. There are gems that help glue things together or you can sort out a `sync` override yourself. Do some googling for "backbone-rails".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a GitHub repo for a ruby gem [backbone-rails](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails) and used the sync override that they included [here](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/backbone_rails_sync.js).

```
Backbone._sync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function (method:string, model:Backbone.Model, options?: any){
    if(options.data == null && model && (method === 'create' || method === 'update' || method === 'patch')) {
        options.contentType = 'application/json';
        var data:any = JSON.stringify(options.attrs || model.toJSON(options));
        if(model.paramRoot) {
            data = {};
            data[model.paramRoot] = model.toJSON(options);
        } else {
            data = model.toJSON();
        }
        options.data = JSON.stringify(data);
    }
    return Backbone._sync(method, model, options);
}
```

I removed some items I didn't need, but this wraps the backbone attributes into an object and sends it to the rails app in the format it needs.

So the parameters:

```
{"email":"test@test.com",
 "password":"123456",
 "password_confirmation":"123456"}
```

Become:

```
{"account":
    {"email":"test@test.com",
     "password":"123456",
     "password_confirmation":"123456"}
}
```

This isn't without a little bit of reworking the backbone application code...

As I am using typescript I had to add the `_sync()` method to the `backbone.d.ts` file using the following signature.

```
declare module Backbone {

    function _sync(method: string, model: Model, options?: JQueryAjaxSettings):any;

    ...
}
```

I also needed to add the following to `Backbone.Model`

```
class Model extends ModelBase implements OptionalDefaults {

    paramRoot: string;

    ...
}
```

And then I added the `paramRoot` property to my model:

```
export class Account extends Backbone.Model {
    public urlRoot: string;
    public validation:any;
    public paramRoot:string;
    constructor(attributes?: any, options?: any){
        this.paramRoot = 'account';
        this.urlRoot = 'http://mydomain.fake/accounts';
        this.validation = {
            email: {
                required: true,
                pattern: 'email'
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minLength: 6
            }
        };
        super(attributes, options);
    }
}
```

There are other ways to allow the `_sync()` method and the `paramRoot` property to pass the compiler errors without modifying the `backbone.d.ts` file but instead extending the objects and adding it in another `.d.ts` file. But this was ok for me as I plan on using this in future projects and I don't mind having the `.d.ts` file being slightly modified.

Hope this helps someone in the future.